# Specify a string is unicode to Python and do not escape slashes

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following string: `s='T,Q0Z+QlT2ElT!A+Z,\u001B\u0003q'` and would like to tell Python this is a Unicode string and have it converted to `u'T,Q0Z+QlT2ElT!A+Z,\u001B\u0003q'`

This **does not work** because the `\` get escaped to `\\`:

```
In [29]: s = 'T,Q0Z+QlT2ElT!A+Z,\u001B\u0003q'

In [30]: u = unicode(s)

In [31]: u
Out[31]: u'T,Q0Z+QlT2ElT!A+Z,\\u001B\\u0003q'
```

Note `s` hasn't been prefixed with the `u` which is the source of the problem. My variable `s` is `s = 'T,Q0Z+QlT2ElT!A+Z,\u001B\u0003q'` and **not** `s = u'T,Q0Z+QlT2ElT!A+Z,\u001B\u0003q'`.

The result I want to get is `u'T,Q0Z+QlT2ElT!A+Z,\u001B\u0003q'` which is equal to  `u'T,Q0Z+QlT2ElT!A+Z,\x1B\x3q` by the way.

Should be simple, but I'm struggling to find the solution. Thanks!

*Edit*: This is Python 2. I cannot add a `u'` before that string `s` because it comes to me that way... Obviously doing something like this `s='u\'' +s` won't work

Comment: Python 2 I guess. Try to put a `u` before it like you see in the output. Also make sure your source encoding is [declared](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) in the first line.

Comment: I can't change the string s. It comes to me that way. I've clarified the question.

Comment: Thanks indeed for the duplicate mention with the answer I was looking for: `s.decode('unicode-escape')`. This solves my problem :)